# How can I bind to multiple elements with the same name in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have about 50 items on my screen.  Each line is a form that contains one select box. Each select box has the same name, "permission_action"

My code:

```
$("#permission_action").change(function() {
    $.ajax({  
      type: "PUT",  
      url: this.form.action,  
      data: "permission[action]=" + $("#permission_action").val()  
    });  
});
```

only binds to the select box in the first form. I want to bind to **all** of the items.

Comment: Do you mean ID? Name is one thing, ID is another.  If you have multiple elements with the same ID, that's an issue.  It's invalid HTML and you can't select multiple elements by the same ID with jQuery.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use CLASS selector instead of ID, as ID suppose to be unique element.

```
<input class="permission_action" ... />
```

in javascript

```
$(".permission_action").change(...);
```

Answer (score 4):

Use a class instead of an ID, which should be unique.

Answer (score 2):

You can bind the ones with the same *name*, not the same *ID*, like this:

```
$("select[name=permission_action]").change(function() {
    $.ajax({  
      type: "PUT",  
      url: this.form.action,  
      data: {"permission[action]" : $(this).val() }
    });  
});
```